# Java 7 DSL representation for spring integration "int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter"

Tags: spring-integration

I have code to read message from IBM MQ with spring integration config as below. I need to convert to Java 7 DSL using Spring integration annotations.

```
<bean id="inQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="esbQueueConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="******" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="readFromChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <!-- <int:wire-tap channel="logger" /> -->
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="jmsInAdapter" connection-factory="esbQueueConnectionFactory"
    destination="inQueue" channel="readFromChannel" />

<bean id="msgProcesser" class="com.gap.si.service.MessageProcessService" />

<int:service-activator id="servAct"
    input-channel="readFromChannel" ref="msgProcesser" method="processMessage" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Java DSL, see the [reference manual](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference).

Use the `Jms` factory class

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDriven...)
                .handle(...)
                .get();
```

If you want to use just annotations, see the [Spring Integration reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations).

The message driven adapter is simply a `@Bean` of type `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` which gets a listener container and a `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener`.

Comment: From which spring dependency we are getting "IntegrationFlows" class. Can i get any sample code which are already developed using this. I'm using Java 7.

Comment: See [the documentation I pointed you too - maven link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#maven). And see the test cases in the project (and documentation) for examples.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your response. I want to know how to implement is Java 7. I have googled a lot, but no where i found useful tutorial. Can you pls provide if you have it handy.

Comment: See [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/01/spring-integration-java-dsl-pre-java-8-line-by-line-tutorial) for a tutorial for using the DSL with Java 7 or earlier.

Comment: Thank you, i'm closing this question